# Comparing two hashes with the keys and values

Tags: perl

I want to compare two hashes, first to see if they key which is in the 1st hash, exists in the 2nd hash and if so compare the values and print a success else if the values are not equal, print the key which has the unequal value.I have gone through some existing similar questions but it confuses me.Hope i can get help.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 6):

The following should help you get an idea:

```
for ( keys %hash1 ) {
    unless ( exists $hash2{$_} ) {
        print "$_: not found in second hash\n";
        next;
    }

    if ( $hash1{$_} eq $hash2{$_} ) {
        print "$_: values are equal\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$_: values are not equal\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that if the values are numerics you should use `==` rather than `eq`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this as part of a test case then you should use `Test::More` `is_deeply` which will compare two complex data structure references together and will print where they differ.

```
use Test::More;
$a = { a => [ qw/a b c/ ], b => { a => 1, b =>2 }, c => 'd' };
$b = { a => [ qw/a b c/ ], b => { a => 2, b =>2 }};
is_deeply($a, $b, 'Testing data structures');

not ok 1 - Testing data structures
#   Failed test 'Testing data structures'
#   at - line 4.
#     Structures begin differing at:
#          $got->{c} = 'd'
#     $expected->{c} = Does not exist
# Tests were run but no plan was declared and done_testing() was not seen.
```

If you need to do this in code then @Alan Haggai Alavi's answer is better.