# Perl compare two hashes based on keys and retrieve values missing in either

Tags: perl, hash, key, compare

Is there a module or best way to compare 2 hashes based on keys and retrieve and print values missing in 1st and 2nd hash?

I have two hashes which describe a particular configuration.
I want to compare two historical statuses of the configuration. In particular I am interested to know which key has been deleted and which key has been added. There is no need to know where the key has been edited (i.e., this does not happen).

Example:

```
Hash 1 keys:
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

Hash 2 keys:
aaa
xxx
bbb
ccc
yyy
```

The result should be something like:

```
xxx added
ddd deleted
yyy added
```

Any idea?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978799/comparing-two-hashes-with-the-keys-and-values

Answer (score 2):

You can use [List::Compare](http://search.cpan.org/~jkeenan/List-Compare-0.38/lib/List/Compare.pm) for this task:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

my %hash1 = map { $_ => undef } qw/aaa bbb ccc ddd/;
my %hash2 = map { $_ => undef } qw/aaa xxx bbb ccc yyy/;

my $lc = List::Compare->new( [ keys %hash1 ], [ keys %hash2 ] );

my @hash1Only = $lc->get_Lonly;
my @hash2Only = $lc->get_Ronly;

print "Added: @hash2Only\nDeleted: @hash1Only\n";
```

Output:

```
Added: xxx yyy
Deleted: ddd
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
sub compare {
  my ($a, $b) = @_;
  [grep !exists $b->{$_}, keys %$a], [grep !exists $a->{$_}, keys %$b];
}

my @keys1 = qw(aaa bbb ccc ddd);
my @keys2 = qw(aaa xxx bbb ccc yyy);
my (%hash1, %hash2);
@hash1{@keys1}=();
@hash2{@keys2}=();
my ($deleted, $added) = compare(\%hash1, \%hash2);
print "Added: @$added, Deleted: @$deleted\n";
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Would this work for a multi-dimensional array? i.e.
my @keys1 = (
    [ "11-AA", "11", "AA", "1.0", "98.375", "48.375", "0.0", "0.0", ],
    [ "22-BB", "22", "BB", "1.0", "97.375", "58.375", "0.0", "0.0", ],);

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all `keys` of hash 1. For each check wether it `exists` in hash 2. If not, it has been deleted. If it does, `delete` the key form hash 2. Once done, all the remaining `keys` in hash 2 are the ones that have been added.

edit: I assume you know how to write code in Perl and just needed an idea. If the answer sounds strange, look the words written `like this` up in Perldoc.

Answer (score 0):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @array1 = qw (aaa bbb ccc ddd);
my @array2 = qw(aaa xxx bbb ccc yyy);
my (%hash1, %hash2);

@hash1{@array1} = 1;
@hash2{@array2} = 1;

foreach (keys %hash2){
    print "added $_\n" unless exists $hash1{$_};
}

foreach (keys %hash1){
    print "removed $_\n" unless exists $hash2{$_}; 
}
```

prints:

```
added xxx
added yyy
removed ddd
```

Comment: @user3098583  no problem. You should select the answer as correct if it achieves what you wanted